# How can I redirect to a page after sending a JQuery get request in rails

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, get

I currently am trying to post a simple GET request from a search page and redirect to another page (a product page).  However, when I send the request, nothing happens and the page does not change.

My code is below:

**javascript**

```
$('.imageBox').click(function () {

        $.get("/s/product/ref", {
            se: search,
            pr: price,
            crr: current,
            bs: best,
            bt: better,
            gd: good
        })
    })
}
```

**main_controller.rb**

```
def product
    respond_to do |format|
      format.js { render :json => @json_data }
    end
    @search = params[:se]
end
```

Comment: use document.location.assign(YOURURL) inside the success ajax call parameter `:/`

Comment: If you're going to redirect the user, why use ajax?

Comment: i needed to pass variables from the previous controller and could not figure out another way to do it

Answer (score 0):

I don't see code to direct the user to a different page. Try using window.location

Comment: thanks.  tried that, but I don't know how to make my url have the correct parameters.  if i do window.location(/s/product/ref/) i get an error.  Is there some sort of callback.

Comment: assuming that /s/product/ref/ is the URL, try this: document.location('/s/product/ref/'); -- the difference is the url has quotes around it.

Comment: that isnt working because the data from the get request doesnt go with the window location

Comment: You would need to add those to the querystring if you want to pass information from one page to the other.